how to align a grid on a specific part of an object
I have a question about how to level this mess, because the labels are placed unevenly. Is there any modifier that will make the grid smooth and not twisted? the remesh modifier did not work

Labels? What labels?

@TheLabCat verts

You can try the 2 Remesh tools in the Data panel > Remesh, or try the app called Instant Meshes that will give a better result
